# setting drop range for wow js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello i try to reach like on this page http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html
if we look at that doge image (right from such easy and right from very JS), the doge image drop to bottom (from way top)

i try to reach that result with this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus velit obcaecati et, tenetur excepturi voluptatum doloremque reprehenderit esse nisi quae necessitatibus facilis provident voluptatem quos, dolorem dicta, modi eos iusto.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus velit obcaecati et, tenetur excepturi voluptatum doloremque reprehenderit esse nisi quae necessitatibus facilis provident voluptatem quos, dolorem dicta, modi eos iusto.</p>

<div class="about-tile">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur commodi saepe atque vitae harum, alias impedit sunt. Praesentium esse voluptatem possimus, autem, tenetur maiores modi ab veritatis nam architecto excepturi!</h2>
  <hr class="divider wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0.5s" >  
</div>
```

or you can see on here:
https://jsfiddle.net/fvjqj7f0/2/

as you can see the result from what i code, the hr only go down a little bit. i need to the hr start go down from `h1` how to do like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is actually due to the `fadeInDown` animation :

`fadeInDown` make it appear a little bit higher than its final place.
In the demo `bounceIndown` is used to drop from the top of the page.

On [animate css website](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) you can have all the availables animations. You can use `fadeInDownBig` to archieve a drop from the top of the page, but i believe that you can't use `wow.js` to drop from a specific position. You should use `keyframes` animations to do so. (with some custom javascript)

[Here is the working example](https://jsfiddle.net/eh7bj3n0/1/)

Comment: Yup i just replaced `fadeInDown` with `fadeInDownBig`. wow.js rely on animatecss. I just didn't know if you really want it to drop from the `h1` place or from the top of the page.